# open the browser after deploying ear project on wildfly

Tags: wildfly

I created a **multi-module-maven** project called [**mission-man**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jhsQ.png).

After right clicking on **mission-man-ear** or **mission-man-web** *> Run As > Run on Server*, the welcome page **welcome.xhtml** is displayed with success.

My problem is: I'd like to display the welcome page with [`another method`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFZrh.png) which is showing **welcome.xhtml** after drag and drop the **mission-man-ear** on **wildfly**.

In other words, I'm looking to show the welcome page **welcome.xhtml** `automatically` after drag and drop the ear project on the server.

Have you please any idea about solving my problem ?. Any help will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is open source, and JBoss Tools (assuming you're using it) is open source.

Therefore you can:

- learn SWT
- checkout the code for Eclipse and JBoss Tools
- figure out how they work
- figure out how to add the drag n drop functionality that you want to the existing code
- modify the Eclipse and/or JBoss Tools code to suit

Comment: Hello Sir @SteveC, thanks a lot for your help. I'm trying to proceed your method without finding a helpful link. if you don't mind, would you please recommend to a specific link?. Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Hello Sir @Aaron, have you please any idea about solving my issue?.